# Compiling log4cplus using MinGW

Tags: c++, compilation, mingw, log4cplus

I have:
- OS: WIndows 7
- MinGW, gcc 4.8.0.
- MSYS 7.2
- Dowloaded log4cplus-1.1.1 from it's [website](http://sourceforge.net/p/log4cplus/wiki/Home/) .

./configure - done well.
But at "make" I receive error with message "undefined reference Mutex::Mutex(Mutex::type)". I searched for ctors for that class inside code, it can be found at:

- log4cplus-1.1.1\include\log4cplus\thread\syncprims-pub-impl.h
- log4cplus-1.1.1\include\log4cplus\thread\impl\syncprims-pthreads.h
- log4cplus-1.1.1\include\log4cplus\thread\impl\syncprims-win32.h

But I don't know how to order comlier use any of them. I checked in MakeFile, they included as include files, I added to config.cxx define WIN32, that still don't work.

How to order my compiler compile log4cplus correctly?

Comment: Try to get [1.1.2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/log4cplus/files/log4cplus-stable/1.1.2/).

Comment: Got same problem:  'log4cplus-1.1.2\loggingserver/../include/log4cplus/helpers/pointer.h:64: undefined reference to `log4cplus::thread::Mutex::Mutex(log4cplus::thread::Mutex::Type)' as was with 1.1.1 version.

Comment: if that will helps, I use http://nuwen.net/mingw.html version 10.0 (you can find it in list below latest version), windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the [patch](https://sourceforge.net/p/log4cplus/bugs/_discuss/thread/a6398bc7/223c/attachment/workaround-for-mingw-linking-issue.patch) attached to ticket [#282](https://sourceforge.net/p/log4cplus/bugs/282). This should be fixed on 1.1.x branch already.

Comment: Thank you! I've made changes that are in patch (they were not fixed in version 1.1.2 I've downloaded from sourceforge), but message "log4cplus-1.1.2\loggingserver/../include/log4cplus/helpers/pointer.h:64: undefined reference to `log4cplus::thread::Mutex::Mutex(log4cplus::thread::Mutex::Type)"
is still there while compiling and it still ends with Error 1.